# How to create a button to mimic link popover feature on gutenberg richtext editor

Tags: javascript, wordpress, ecmascript-6, wordpress-gutenberg, ecmascript-next

I need to create a button, that will generate a tag with `data-footnote` attribute and it will be editable, just like the link popover that comes when you click it. That's what I tried so far, but the popover doesn't shows at all, I need that this button works exactly like the link button but instead, it changes my data-note attribute with a textbox instead of that input that shows when you click the link button.

This code below is what I've done so far. The button is there, it worsk to create my tag exactly as I need it, but I'm having a hard time finding how to make the popover appear so I can inline edit that data attribute.

```
import { Fragment } from '@wordpress/element';
import { RichTextToolbarButton, RichTextShortcut } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
import {
    toggleFormat,
    registerFormatType,
} from '@wordpress/rich-text';

const name = `custom/eos-footnote`;

export const footnote = {
    name,
    title: 'Footnote',
    tagName: 'span',
    className: 'eos-footnote',
    attributes: {
        //'data-note': 'data-note',
    },
    edit( { isActive, value, onChange } ) {
        const onToggle = () => {
            onChange(
                toggleFormat( value, {
                    type: name,
                    attributes: {
                        'data-note': 'Please type your note here',
                    },
                } )
            );
        };
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <RichTextShortcut
                    type="primary"
                    character="n"
                    onUse={ onToggle }
                />
                <RichTextToolbarButton
                    icon="admin-post"
                    title={ 'Footnote' }
                    onClick={ onToggle }
                    isActive={ isActive }
                    shortcutType="primary"
                    shortcutCharacter="n"
                />
            </Fragment>
        );

    },
};

function registerFormats () {
    [
        footnote,
    ].forEach( ( { name, ...settings } ) => registerFormatType( name, settings ) );
};

registerFormats();
```

Answer (score -2):

[google](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/components/popover/#top)
this link i found it helpful check it out
Render a Popover within the parent to which it should anchor:

```
    import { Button, Popover } from '@wordpress/components';
    import { withState } from '@wordpress/compose';

    const MyPopover = withState( {
        isVisible: false,
    } )( ( { isVisible, setState } ) => {
        const toggleVisible = () => {
            setState( ( state ) => ( { isVisible: ! state.isVisible } ) );
        };
        return (
            <Button isSecondary onClick={ toggleVisible }>
                Toggle Popover!
                { isVisible && (
                    <Popover>
                        Popover is toggled!
                    </Popover>
                ) }
            </Button>
        );
    } );
```

If a Popover is returned by your component, it will be shown. To hide the popover, simply omit it from your component’s render value.

If you want Popover elements to render to a specific location on the page to allow style cascade to take effect, you must render a Popover.Slot further up the element tree:

```
import { render } from '@wordpress/element';
import { Popover } from '@wordpress/components';
import Content from './Content';

const app = document.getElementById( 'app' );

render(
    <div>
        <Content />
        <Popover.Slot />
    </div>,
    app
);
```